# Change working directory with another directory in plumber R

Tags: r, function, api, plumber, setwd

I am Creating Web Application with Plumber API in R. I was trying to change the working directory using plumber.

Currently the file is in `C:/xampp/htdocs/testMDA` i was trying to change the directory with `C:\fileUpload\abc`. **abc** is passed as argument in function

```
library(plumber)

#* @get /string
getString <- function(get = ""){
  dir <- setwd(file.path("C:/fileUpload/", get))
  print(dir)
}
```

and output i get this which is current directory

```
"C:/xampp/htdocs/testMDA"
```

Comment: try `print(getwd())` instead as setwd will return the current wd

Comment: @SinhNguyen my intention is not to print working directory. Aim is to change the directory using plumber.

Comment: What I mean is after you `setwd()` you need to use `getwd()` to get the current workding directory. `setwd()` doesn't return the new value it set.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid naming arguments like base functions (get in your function). I don't see where you use plumber in your example. What happens if you run the following code (assuming the folder "fileUpload" exists)? If it runs, you can insert it into your function.

```
dir <- file.path("C:/fileUpload/", "abc")
setwd(dir)
getwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

my question itself has answer. Think is that In plumber directory gets change to `C:\fileUpload\abc` but plumber won't show this instead plumber print its working directory where it is running.

Let's see what is happening!

When plumber is running. It is running in its root folder it will print its root full path. It does change the directory in `plumber swagger` but won't print `getwd`. My Aim is to change the directory.